# Adding another partition to 14.04 - what mount-point/settings needed?

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, partitioning, wine

Firstly sorry if this is a bit too detailed for this kind of question but I fear not telling you enough to be able to help me!

So, I have a duel boot (UEFI) laptop which had Win7 on it which I shrank and installed extra partitions (gpt) and then added Ubuntu. I'm aiming not to return to Win7 other than for a few bits I need for work BUT when I started adding my favourite games with Wine I found I didn't have enough space on my partitions BUT again, I do actually have some free space on the drive, which Parted table from is at the bottom of this post. Between Partition 5 (SWAP) and 12 (some random reset stuff that came with the laptop and I do want rid of eventually but not yet), is, according to Disks, 50Gb free-space. I want to make partition(s) out of this that I can use but I'm not entirely clear re: what mount-point and so on to use for this extra partition. I've never gone 'outside of the box' in this way before - I've only ever stuck to normal partition structures. I want Wine to be able to access it, obviously, and want to run games from it, basically.

My existing structure is below - 6 = root, 7 = /boot, 8 = /usr, 9 = /var, 10 = /tmp, 11 = /home, 12 = SWAP. I don't really want to do a clean install and just make /usr bigger - I'd like to just add another partition but I don't know what to call it etc - can someone please advise what is best to do in this circumstance?
Thanks
r

> Partition Table: gpt

```
Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  420MB  419MB   ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      420MB   735MB  315MB   fat32           EFI system partition          boot
 3      735MB   869MB  134MB                   Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      869MB   361GB  360GB   ntfs            Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      361GB   377GB  16.0GB  ext4
 7      377GB   377GB  300MB   ext4
 8      377GB   384GB  7000MB  ext4
 9      384GB   397GB  13.0GB  ext4
10      397GB   398GB  500MB   ext4
11      398GB   405GB  7000MB  ext4
12      405GB   416GB  11.0GB  linux-swap(v1)
 5      466GB   500GB  34.1GB  ntfs            Basic data partition          hidden, diag
```

Comment: How about you create a directory `/games` or such, you create a new partition, you configure `/etc/fstab` to mount that partition at `/games`, and you put all your games there. As a filesystem, if you only intend to run Windows games with `wine` I would suggest `ntfs` as this is what these games expect and Linux is able to access NTFS partitions just fine nowadays. Also, you would be able to access that partition from Windows, if needed.

Answer (score 0):

- Create and format the partition using the 'Disks' system application.  Note the 'Device' id and 'Type' of the partition.
- sudo mkdir /games
- sudo vi /etc/fstab
- The first column will be the device id, the second column, will be where you want the partition mounted, the third column is the 'type', the fourth column are different options (see "man fstab" for more information), the fifth and sixth column are sometimes used by different backup utilities (again, see "man fstab" for more information)

The final fstab entry might look something like this:

```
/dev/sdb1       /games ext4    defaults       0       0
```

If you choose to use ntfs as another poster mentioned, then you might have a couple more options.  Here's what the fstab line might look like.

```
/dev/sdb1       /games ntfs    defaults,umask=007,gid=46       0       0
```

If you already have your windows drive mounted/available to see, you might already have a line like that in your file.  I would copy that line and use the same options.